# PHPMAILER mail sent but not received

Tags: email, phpmailer

I am trying to use PHPMailer but I'm having problem. This is my test code:

```
<?php

require './PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();

$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;

$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

$mail->Host = "localhost";
//Set the SMTP port number - likely to be 25, 465 or 587
$mail->Port = 25;

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

$mail->Username = "donotreply@myservermail";

$mail->Password = "mypassword";

$mail->setFrom('donotreply@myservermail', 'Mail test');

$mail->addReplyTo('myemail@live.com', 'First Last');

$mail->addAddress('donotreply@myservermail', 'Test mail');

$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer SMTP test';


$mail->msg = 'Hello there this is a test . ';

$mail->Body = 'This is a plain-text message body';

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}

?>
```

And here is the result from browser, and I see no error there:

```
Connection: opening to localhost:25, timeout=300, options=array ()
Connection: opened
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 localhost ESMTP"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220 localhost ESMTP"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 localhost ESMTP
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO MY_SERVER_NAME
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-localhost"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-localhost"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-localhost"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SIZE 20480000"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-localhost250-SIZE 20480000"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-localhost250-SIZE 20480000"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-AUTH LOGIN"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-localhost250-SIZE 20480000250-AUTH LOGIN"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-localhost250-SIZE 20480000250-AUTH LOGIN"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 HELP"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-localhost250-SIZE 20480000250-AUTH LOGIN250 HELP"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-localhost250-SIZE 20480000250-AUTH LOGIN250 HELP
Auth method requested: UNKNOWN
Auth methods available on the server: LOGIN
Auth method selected: LOGIN
CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "334 SOME_ENCRYPTED_STRING"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "334 SOME_ENCRYPTED_STRING"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 SOME_ENCRYPTED_STRING
CLIENT -> SERVER: SOME_ENCRYPTED_STRING
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "334 SOME_ENCRYPTED_STRING"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "334 SOME_ENCRYPTED_STRING"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 SOME_ENCRYPTED_STRING
CLIENT -> SERVER: SOME_ENCRYPTED_STRING
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "235 authenticated."
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "235 authenticated."
SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 authenticated.
CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<donotreply@MY_SERVER_MAIL>
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 OK"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250 OK"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK
CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<MY_EMAIL@yahoo.com>
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 OK"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250 OK"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK
CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "354 OK, send."
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "354 OK, send."
SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 OK, send.
CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Thu, 14 May 2015 10:40:00 +0200
CLIENT -> SERVER: To: MY_EMAIL yahoo <MY_EMAIL@yahoo.com>
CLIENT -> SERVER: From: MAIL_SERVER test <donotreply@MY_SERVER_MAIL>
CLIENT -> SERVER: Reply-To: MY_EMAIL Live <MY_EMAIL@live.com>
CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: PHPMailer SMTP test
CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <SOME_ENCRYPED_STRING@MY_SERVER_NAME>
CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Priority: 3
CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.10 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/)
CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
CLIENT -> SERVER:
CLIENT -> SERVER: This is a plain-text message body
CLIENT -> SERVER:
CLIENT -> SERVER: .
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 Queued (0.000 seconds)"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250 Queued (0.000 seconds)"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Queued (0.000 seconds)
CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "221 goodbye"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "221 goodbye"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 goodbye
Connection: closed
Message sent!
```

I've tried this test with different emails, on yahoo, gmail, etc, but still the same. I also checked carefully the spam for all my emails, for couple hours.
Any idea?

Comment: Please repost the results as code not as an image.

Comment: I just did it @Patryk :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It *is* succeeding - in delivering to localhost, as you're asking it to. What happens after that is entirely outside PHPMailer's control. You need to look at your local mail server's log to see what happens after that, but it looks like it's not getting any further than that, so you need to look at your mail server's config.